# twitter api request restrictions?

Tags: twitter

I believe that twitter is hiding something from us.. I'm creating a twitter crawler and trying to respect twitter's official restrictions of 350 requests per hour, but it seems there are more of them? Maybe per minute, or 15-minute-window?

Although my script never goes over 350 requests per hour, sometimes I can get an 'you exceeded your rate' error, which if I wait a few minutes it goes away.

Can anyone confirm any other limitations you have observed on smaller windows than 1 hour?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rate limits in version 1.1 of the API are divided into 15 minute intervals, which is a change from the 60 minute blocks in version 1.0.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1